# Copy a selected value from Select box into clipboard by a click on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

If I have a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select id="links" name="links">
        <option value="http://something.com">Link 1</option>
        <option value="http://somethingelse.com">Link 2</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#">Copy to Clipboard</a>
</form>
```

What would I need to add to it so a click on the linked text actually copied the selected value from the select box?

It could be jQuery or regular javascript, regardless...

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [plugin](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) for jQuery doing this, also You have to use flash for this 'coz it's not possible to do this in `normal` way.